# What is the equivalent of stamper.AddJavaScript function (iText 5) with iText7 (.NET)?

Tags: itext7

We are writing a program that needs to insert document-level
JavaScript with iText 7. We founded that with iText 5, the solution was Stamper.AddJavaScript().

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of event you want your `JavaScript` code to be triggered at.

For instance, to define an action that would be executed as soon as the document is opened, use `PdfDocument#getCatalog().setOpenAction`.

Example for opening a print dialog when the document is opened:

```
pdfDocument.getCatalog().setOpenAction(PdfAction.createJavaScript("this.print(true);"));
```

Comment: To be more specific, we would like for example to validate with javascript methods witch can be more than 100 lines long or complex answer after modification of a field data

Comment: In fact, what we would like to be able to do is something like Stamper.addJavaScript(Utilities.readFileToString(".../filename.js") where ".../filename.js" is a file with javascript methods (example seen in iText 5 documentation).

Comment: And to finish, it seems that we can incorporate javascript methods at document level javascript in a PDF file. It is true, and wouldit be possible to do so with iText ?