# Equivalent of stamper.addJavaScript function in iText7 (.NET)

Tags: javascript, itext7

We are writing a program that needs to insert document-level JavaScript with iText 7. We found that with iText 5, the solution was `Stamper.AddJavaScript()`.

The example seen in the iText 5 is something like

```
Stamper.addJavaScript(Utilities.readFileToString(".../filename.js")
```

where `".../filename.js"` is a file containing javascript methods. 
In our case, we would like to refer to our javascript library.

And to finish, it seems that we can incorporate Javascript methods at document level directly inside the PDF file.

Is it true ?
If so, would it be possible to do so with iText ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of stamper.AddJavaScript function (iText 5) with iText7 (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751255/what-is-the-equivalent-of-stamper-addjavascript-function-itext-5-with-itext7)

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new File("output.pdf"));
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);

// dirty hack to read entire file at once
String js = new Scanner(new File("javascript_to_embed.js")).useDelimiter("\\z").next();

// set action
pdfDocument.getCatalog().setOpenAction(PdfAction.createJavaScript(js));

// add some content

// close document
pdfDocument.close();
```